# Sound is muffled/broken and video is basically impossible to play

Tags: sound, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu two weeks ago and it has been amazing. However there has been one problem that isn't going away. The sound is muffled/broken.
I don't understand what's happening. Does anyone have a fix for it?

Comment: Does it happen during media playback or system-wide? If it only happens during media playback then  install & use Gnome MPV `sudo apt install gnome-mpv`.